# Running PHP as CGI script on Mongoose in Windows

Tags: php, cgi

So I have downloaded `mongoose-5.0.exe` on my Win7.

I followed the *How to setup PHP* from [here](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/mongoose-vanilla/wiki/Windows-Usage) and copied php-cgi.exe and php5.dll to my root directory and set the config files:

**mongoose.conf**

```
cgi_interpreter C:\Projects\Netio\php-cgi.exe
cgi_pattern **.cgi$|**.lp$|**.php$
document_root C:\Projects\Netio
listening_port 80
error_log_file errors.log
```

**php.ini**

```
short_open_tag = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 10
memory_limit = 16M
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
doc_root = "C:\Projects\Netio"
extension_dir = "C:\Projects\Netio"
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello";?>
```

However, the browser tells me that there is no response from index.php. Static html is displayed correctly and 127.0.0.1 pings well. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

enclose your PHP code with HTML tags and try again

`<html>
<?php....
?>
</html>`

Also, make sure your PHP extension dir is correctly specified.
Usually when you extract PHP, it contains "ext" dir, and i can see you are pointing to the main PHP folder in your extension parameter in php.ini

Side note: I am using the free version of Mangoose 6.5, and for me it wont open any PHP file, except file named index.php.

Comment: It could be that doc_root can't be the same as cgi_interpreter dir. I ended up using mongoose 4 package where the doc_root was a subdir of cgi_interpreter. It worked and php.ini was absent there, so it is irrelevant for cgi I guess. I made no further investigations, since the mongoose 4 works for me "as is".